# Identify an American TV Show Car Chase - Aired in early 2000's

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

The American TV show was staged. It was almost like a game-show in which they drove to an isolated or abandoned town, and a "criminal" would be selected. The criminal could select to be in any type of car they wanted. There were be 3 or 4 cops in patrol units on the show, driving around the abandoned town. The cops would be alerted a description of the criminal car, and have to stop the vehicle before it left the perimeter of the town. If the criminal got past the perimeter, he won a prize. If the cops worked together and stopped the criminal before he reached the perimeter, they won a prize.

I remember one episode vividly in which a criminal selected to be in a large box truck, and had 2 or 3 marked units chasing him. While 3 patrol units were chasing the box truck, the back of the box truck opened up, and he drove out of it going the other direction in a convertible and made it past the perimeter. I would really like to watch this tv show again. Any ideas? I think I am leaning towards it being aired in the early 2000's. Thanks!

Comment: There was a similar Russian gameshow like that once called [Intercept (or Interception)](http://carhumor.net/russian-extreme-game-show-the-interception/) in 1997-1998. Can't find any clips, though.

Comment: What country was this in?

Comment: Thank you Walt and Johnny Bones.  The TV show aired in the United States, and as Walt eluded to, was called "Getaway."

If interested, I found an episode of Intercept: 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sLXND1tinUM

Thank you both for the quick response, I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for an American show, there's UPN's gameshow(?) *Getaway* from the early 2000s. There isn't lot of info about this one either, but from a report:

> From Paul Stojanovich, the executive producer of 'Worlds Wildest Police Videos', 'Getaway' aims to bring the dramatic car-chase scenes back to TV by taking four of the boys in blue and put them to the test, attempting to capture cars stunt and racing-car drivers.

Here's a clip from the show similar to the one you're describing, where one of the competitors drives a tow-truck and then fools the cops by driving away in the towed car (and it all looks fake as hell):

Comment: Thank you for finding this for me!  This is it!  Of course, I remember it being much cooler than it looks now, but this is a trip down memory lane for me.  Thank you!

Comment: I think they had Jessie James on this show once. It was pretty fun.